# Checking toggle button state in android?

Tags: android, toggle

How to  maintain the state of toggle buttons, like if we press button1 then it remembers the on state of button1 and won't allow us to press button2, and vice versa.
 Please help me out in solving this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

Declare variables

```
ToggleButton mToggleOne;
ToggleButton mToggleTwo;
```

In `onCreate`

```
mToggleOne = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle_button1);
mToggleTwo = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggle_button2);

SharedPreferences spref = getSharedPreferences();
if(spref.getBoolean("one", false)) {
    mToggleOne.setChecked(true);
    mToggleTwo.setEnabled(false);    
} else if(spref.getBoolean("two", false)) {
    mToggleTwo.setChecked(true);
    mToggleOne.setEnabled(false);    
}
mToggleOne.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       mToggleTwo.setEnabled(!isChecked);
       getSharedPreferences().edit()
           .putBoolean("one", isChecked)
           .apply();
       //other code
    }
});

mToggleTwo.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
       mToggleOne.setEnabled(!isChecked);
       getSharedPreferences().edit()
           .putBoolean("two", isChecked)
           .apply();
       //other code
    }
});
```

Comment: ohh yeah I did that :)

Comment: but a simple problem occurred, actually side by side i was saving the state of toggle button, but after applying this code its not saving the state of toggle button anymore.

Comment: @Sam where do you wanna save it? You can try onSaveInstanceState like here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html
Or try to put into preferences, like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Comment: actually i want button1 should remain "on" until and unless i want to off the button, so for that i have to save the state of toggle button that it it should remember it is on. Same for the button2

Comment: @Sam you can call mToggleOne.isChecked() to retrieve info about state

Comment: but its not working after pressing the backkey to the app, when i opened it, both button setChecked.(off)

Comment: To make everything clear:
You wanna retrieving states of the toggled buttons after closing and opening app? Or after going to another activity and coming back?

Comment: i want to retrieve the states of the toggled buttons after closing and opening app.

Comment: Yes! thank you so very much :) it is working perfectly :) Stay Blessed